# Did Bryan have two separate hotel rooms?

Tags: plot-explanation, taken-2

I am somewhat confused as to what happens in the hotel. The bad guys go to the girl's room, but don't find her. They then go to her dad's room, but didn't find her in there but see the open window. One goes left and one goes right. The girl is in the closet with the suit case with her dad's equipment.

Was this just a room with the door locked, or did Bryan have two separate hotel rooms adjoined with a door?

Comment: I for myself didn't get why one of the bad guys shot some other random guy that sat in another room while the other bad guy was checking the closet.

Answer (score 2):

Both rooms had beds so it was definitely not just an extra office. It might be that he just wanted an extra room to keep his security stuff. It could also be a room rented for someone else on the security team (that left with the client). Both rooms seemed to be fully equipped to act as singles.

Comment: He booked two adjoining rooms, so that he wasn't staying in a hotel room that had a vulnerable door in it to another room that someone with nefarious intentions could book.